# the new 0.9.2 update seems to be broken

Tags: aframe

In the latest (06/25/2019) update to A-frame, it seems like it is broken.

It won't even load the scene, on Chrome 75, and devtools console shows the following errors:

```
device.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: navigator.xr.requestDevice is not a 
function
at Object.<anonymous> (device.js:18)
at Object.176._process (device.js:142)
at o (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.179../bind (index.js:6)
at o (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.152.../package (index.js:25)
at o (_prelude.js:1)
at r (_prelude.js:1)
```

I've been a long time Aframe user, and have never encountered this problem before. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a known chrome issue. Click on `Reset all to default`on chrome://flags.